# Multisite tax configuration: Different tax rate for same country in multi website

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, taxes

What is the best way to configure tax in the following scenario:
I have two websites:
Site A:

> - tax rates: 0, 9, 21
> - countries NL, BE
> - all tax rates are applicable to both countries

Site B:

> - tax rates: 0, 9, 21
> - countries: NL, BE
> - all tax rates applicable to NL only
> - For BE no tax is applied.

Products are configured to have tax class 0% BTW or 9% BTW or 21% BTW.
If I select 21% BTW for a product then for site A it works without an issue, but for site B, I cannot make it 21% when NL is selected as the country in checkout and 0% when BE is selected.
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Create TAX rule and rate different for each site and assign TAX class website wise within the product.

[image]

Comment: yes i have applied the tax class. But if I apply tax class, say, 21%BTW to a product, it will have the same class for both BE and NL countries.

Comment: Tax class - All applicable NL BE
create - 0 NL
create - 9 NL
create - 21 NL
create - 0 BE
create - 9 BE
create - 21 BE
Tax class - All applicable NL
create - 0 NL
create - 9 NL
create - 21 NL

In Product site A: Tax class - All applicable NL BE 
In Product site B: Tax class - All applicable NL

Comment: i don't understand your previous comment. Could you clarify it a bit more?